# How to pass method with arguments to Callable

Tags: java, multithreading, future, callable

I am trying to implement Multithreading with Callable/Future in my Raytracer, by splitting up the process by each row/column.
To do this I need to pass variables from my Main to Callable, which is not accepting arguments.

I tried passing the whole function as callable

This is the function I am trying to multithread, 'formen' is my Group of objects I'm passing.
Sending rays and finding intersections is what needs most computing power-

```java
    static Image raytrace(Camera camera, Group formen, int samples){
        Image image = new Image(camera.width, camera.height);

        for (int x = 0; x != camera.width; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y != camera.height; y++) {

                Vec3 color = new Vec3(0, 0, 0);
                for (int xi = 0; xi < samples; xi++) {
                    for (int yi = 0; yi < samples; yi++) {
                        double rx = random.nextDouble();
                        double ry = random.nextDouble();
                        double xs = x + (xi + rx) / samples;
                        double ys = y + (yi + ry) / samples;

                        Ray ray = camera.sendRay(xs,ys);
                        Hit hit = formen.intersect(ray);
                        if(hit != null) color = Vec3.add(color, calculateRadiance(formen, ray, 100));
                    }
                }
                color = Vec3.divide(color, Math.pow(samples, 2));
                image.setPixel(x, y, color);
            }
        }
        return image;
    }
```

This is what my tracing function looks like:

```java
        int cores = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
        Thread[] threads = new Thread[cores];
        Image[] images = new Image[cores];
        // Pool creation
        ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);
        //images[core] = raytrace(camera, scene, nn);
        for(int i = 0; i < camera.height; i++){
            Future<Image> pixel = pool.submit(calculateOneRow);
            //threads[i].start();
            System.out.println("Thread started:");
            pool.shutdown();
            try {
                System.out.println("Image written");
                return pixel.get();
                //Image color = pixel.get();
            } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            final long duration = (System.nanoTime() - startTime) / 1000000;
            return image;
        }
```

In think the inner for loop has to go into my Callable but I don't know how to pass them each as separate task.
My goal is to reduce the render time.

Comment: Crete callable tha will have those argumenst stored already.

Comment: yes, that's why I put the whole raytrace function inside the callable. But if I just put the for loop for the width inside, I can't calculate ys.

Comment: He means make a constructor in your callable subclass that takes the same parameters as `raytrace()` and `x` and `y` as well. (if your callable should calculate one pixel. Or skip the `y` if your callable should render an entire row)

Comment: Thanks to the both of you, that worked!